# How to find out the reason Visual Studio 2015 Community crash on start

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash

I have booted my PC, started VS 2015 Community. Logo window shows up and almost instantly crashes without any messages but with error sound. Exact sound I have found in sound settings of Windows 7 described as "Default sound" or "Standard sound" (I have not english version).

In the last session (yesterday) it worked normally and here wasn't any changes in the system.

How could I find out reason of this crash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have any error message. So, I have two methods to resolve your problem.

---

*Method 1:*

Since you're able to run with another user login, something may be wrong with your local settings, you can try to reset them: `devenv /resetsettings` in `Start menu -> Run`.

**Warning: this will restore visual studio to default settings.**

---

*Method 2:*

Read this article:

http://blog.masterdevs.com/debugging-a-visual-studio-crash/